# Alexa ignores slots

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I want to use slots in my intent, but when I try to fill one at the simulator, alexa will ignore the slot. I can start my intent without saying a slot value, but if I try to say a value Alexa fails to start the intent.

I use a custom slot type, but I already tried a Amazon predefined. There I got the same issue.

I tried with an other language. (first German, then English)

And I use Python as SDK

Answer (score 0):

If you could share your configuration of intents, slot types and the test protocol from the simulator maybe the cause could be discovered. Otherwise the description of this problem is unfortunately too generic.